# Double size of Inline Shapes

Tags: vba, ms-word

New to coding and if someone could please give me a hand would greatly appreciate the help. The code is supposed to output a message when there are no inline shapes, and when there are inline shapes...It is to double the ratio of inline shape (size*2).

I've run into a few issues...The code does not notice that there are inline shapes in the document...nor does it change the aspect/size of the inline shapes either.

Thanks!

```
Sub InlineShapesModify ()
Dim RangeShape As word.Range
Set RangeShape = ActiveDocument.Content
Dim ShapeCount As Integer

ShapeCount = 0
With RangeShape.Find
    .Forward = True
    .Execute
    Do While .Found
        ShapeCount = ShapeCount + 1
        RangeShape.Collapse word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
        .Execute
    Loop
End With

If (ShapeCount = 0) Then
    MsgBox ("No images to modify")
    Exit Sub
ElseIf (ShapeCount > 0) Then
Do While (ShapeCount > 0)
    ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(i).Height = _
    ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(i).Height * 2
    Loop
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all you want to do is double the height and width of all of your inline shapes, with a message if no inline shapes are present in the document, this should work:

```
Sub ilshapes()
    Dim h As Long, w As Long, rng As Range, sh As InlineShape

    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content

    If rng.InlineShapes.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No images to modify."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each sh In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        h = sh.Height
        w = sh.Width

        sh.Height = 2 * h
        sh.Height = 2 * w
    Next sh

    MsgBox rng.InlineShapes.Count & " images modified."
End Sub
```